# Modifying content copied to the clipboard to increase readability

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, clipboard

I need a way, using either clever HTML/CSS hacks or JavaScript/jQuery, to modify what content is taken away from an element when copied.

I'm making a chatroom for my website. It features the user's avatar, the relative timestamp, the user's name, and a message. It's a really friendly design that jives well with the people who've used it.

[image]

The problem with this is that it doesn't copy to the clipboard tidily. The alt text of the avatar is the user's name, so when you highlight a line of chat and copy it, this is what you end up with:

> Guest Today at 7:41 PM - Guest: test
>   Guest Today at 8:05 PM - Guest: test
>   Guest Today at 9:29 PM - Guest: Chat message text

It's really nasty. I'd like to preserve the user friendliness of having an avatar and a relative timestamp, but modify what is copied to be like a typical IRC log, like this:

> [2014-09-20 7:41pm] Guest: test
>   [2014-09-20 8:05pm] Guest: test
>   [2014-09-20 9:29pm] Guest: Chat message text

I'd greatly appreciate any input on this.